# Call of overloaded method with nullptr is ambiguous

Tags: c++, overloading, nullptr

I have some overloaed methods which take some different pointer types.
Now I want to call one specific method with `nullptr` as a parameter.

I know that I could cast the `nullptr` to the specific type of pointer, the method I want it to call takes.
But I don't want to/can't cast the `nullptr`.

This example shoud explain what I am trying to do:

```
class Foo {
    //some attributes
};
class Bar {
    //some attributes
};

void myMethod (Foo*) {
    //I want this method to be called
}
void myMethod (Bar*) {
    //Not this one
}

int main () {
    myMethod(nullptr);              //Something like this
//  myMethod(static_cast<nullptr>); //I don't want to write this.

    return 0;
}
```

If I just call it with the `nullptr` I get
`error: call of overloaded 'myMethod(std::nullptr_t)' is ambiguous`
because the compiler doesn't know which of the methods it should call.

Is there a way to do what I want?
Like something similar to the template specialization?

Comment: I forgot about this question and didn't close nor respond to it because the issue was fixed. Turns out I could use `myMethod(static_cast<Foo*>(nullptr));` after all.

Comment: It will be better if you could accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an overload which take [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t) as argument, and then in it call the exact function wanted (through casting):

```
void myMethod(std::nullptr_t)
{
    myMethod(static_cast<Foo*>(nullptr));
}
```

Comment: would a method w/o parameters be OK too?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko That could be used too, but of course depends on the requirements and wishes of the OP. Then a simple default argument like `void myMethod(Foo* = nullptr)` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

You can create pointer of Foo and Bar and let both point to nullptr. Now you can call a overloaded function by passing pointer variable as argument.

```
class Foo {
    //some attributes
};
class Bar {
    //some attributes
};

void myMethod (Foo*) {
    //I want this method to be called
}
void myMethod (Bar*) {
    //Not this one
}

int main () {
    Foo* foo=nullptr;
    Bar* bar=nullptr;
    myMethod(foo);              //This will call myMethod(Foo*)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056250/4143855) has a good suggestion, but you could also add a default parameter to one of your methods if you were happy to call it without passing `nullptr`, like so:

```
void myMethod (Foo* = nullptr) {}
void myMethod (Bar*) {}

int main () {
    myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Like something similar to the template specialization?

If that means that you wish to specify the target class on a case by case basis, you can turn the overload in [@Some programmer dude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056250/817643) into a template.

```
template<class C>
void myMethod(std::nullptr_t) {
    myMethod(static_cast<C*>(nullptr));
}
```

Now you can use a simple template name to call the overload you want

```
myMethod<Foo>(nullptr); // What you want now.
myMethod<Bar>(nullptr); // What you may want at another point.
myMethod<Baz>(nullptr); // What you may want sometime in the future,
                        // after adding another overload.
```

Comment: why pass the `nullptr` if anyhow thats the only allowed value for that overload? I mean `myMethod<Foo>();` would also do it. Well...might be that there are situations where this makes sense

Comment: @user463035818 - It's not the only allowed value. Common other options include `0`, `NULL`, and probably other integral constant expressions with the value 0. Though I suppose it does look funny. I'll keep it, let it be just one step in refactoring.